# ng-table : Clear table contents on button click

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am able to show data on button click. How to clear table contents on clear?

**HTML**

```
 <div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="tableControl as vm">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.show()">Show</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.clear()">Clear</button>
    <table ng-table="vm.tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
      <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
          {{user.name}}</td>
        <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
          {{user.age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tried setting *tableParams* to null but did not help.

```
  self.show = function() {
    self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
      page: 1, // show first page
      count: 10 // count per page
    }, {
      dataset: data
    });
  }

  self.clear = function() {
  self.tableParams = null;
  }
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santushet/p71w5u2k/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not gonna work, because you have to clear the `dataset` object instead.

Reset the `dataset` array and call `reload()` function:

```
self.clear = function() {
    self.tableParams.settings().dataset = [];
    self.tableParams.reload();
}
```

... and it's gonna work! :)

Comment: I don't think ``self.tableParams.reload();`` is needed, besides if you are using ``getData: function()`` instead of ``dataset: data`` when you call ``reload()`` the function will trigger again so ``self.tableParams.dataset = []`` should be enough